# Using XSL IF to check if the element appears in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file:

```
    <club>
      <person>
        <name>name</name>
        <ranking>1</ranking>
        <nationality>spanish</nationality>
        <joined>2007</joined>
        <joined>2009</joined >
      </person>

      <person>
        <name>name</name>
        <ranking>2</ranking>
        <nationality>english</nationality>
      </person>
    </club>
```

I would like to create an XSLT file that can search through the XML and check whether the person has joined (`<joined>`). Then I would want to display the name and the year the person joined in a table. I am not sure if this is entirely possible, but any help would be greatly appreciated. (not all the people on the list will have joined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="information">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="person[joined]">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="joined" separator=", "/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

See transformation for **XSLT 2.0** at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEZ

For **XSLT 1.0** you can change second `td` to

```
<td><xsl:for-each select="joined">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each></td>
```

Transformation for **XSLT 1.0** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEZ/1

Comment: @A6784, See transformation at [https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEZ/2](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEZ/2)

Comment: You can use  `<xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>` inside `xsl:for-each` where `@order` can be `descending` or `ascending`, see [https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEZ/4](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEZ/4)